# Glyphicon not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am trying to use a glyphicon in one of my menu items and here is what I used:

```
 <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-home"></span>Home</a> </li>
```

I have following files in head section:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But the glyphicon does not seem to work at all. What could be the problem ?

Comment: It's `glyphicon` (no `s`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add fonts folder to your directory, parallel to css file from bootstrap. Glyphicons are fonts which bootstrap uses.

Your html code is also slightly wrong.

**For glyphicons, css class is `glyphicon` and you are using `glyphicons`.**

Check [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) for reference.

Comment: the fonts directory isn't the issue, as are pointing to the CDN, which was the fonts.  but the added(s) would appear to be the issue.

Comment: Check next section of my answer, there is spelling mistake in class name.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange: Thank you. It worked, I had used glyphicons thing from here : http://glyphicons.com/ and for the icons, it asks to use glyphicons only. Am I confusing it with something else?